# Getting getting "not found" and "already exists" for the same github repo

Tags: java, macos, git, github, terminal

I have a git repo with one project called Dogs. Now I am trying to add another project called Chair. So to  add the Chair project I do as follows

- Go to Github and create a repo wit the name chair
- in terminal go to my /chair directory and run `git init`
- git add —all .
- git commit -m 'First commit'
- copy my url from github and in terminal enter `git remote add origin https://github.com/myname/chair.git`
- git push origin master

Then I get the error

remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myname/chair.git/' not found

finding this error strange, I retyped

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myname/chair.git
```

Sure enough this one gave the error `fatal: remote origin already exists.` So how is it possible that I am getting `not found` and `already exists` for the same repo? I know there are similar questions here, but none of them was able to help me.

Note: I am suspecting that somehow my first repo, `dog`, is interfering with my present repo `chair`. But why would that be? It's been almost two months, but I believe I followed the exact steps when creating `dog` and certainly I have been updating `dog` daily without an issue.

**update**

I remove origin with `git remote rm origin` and then did the exact same steps anew, but this time replacing all occurrences of `origin` with `chair`. I still end up with the same `not found` but when I try `git push chair master`

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding remote chair for your new git repo.

```
<code>
git remote add chair https://github.com/myname/chair.git
</code>
```

After making the changes and issuing commit,Please use the below command to push the code.

```
<code>
git push chair master
</code>
```

Comment: why `dog`? dog is an entirely different folder/repo. As a matter of fact, I already did a few things: I removed the `origin` remote and then recreated everything where I use `chair` instead of `origin`. But I still end up with the same `not found` error. I also verified remote with `-v` and everything looks fine, but when I try to push: `not found`.

Comment: Can you please paste the output of `git remote -v`

Comment: `chair https://github.com/myname/chair.git (fetch)`
`chair https://github.com/myname/chair.git (push)`

Comment: Please try making chair as origin and try using the below commands.

    `git remote rm chair`
    `git remote add origin https://github.com/myname/chair.git`
    `git push origin master`
    
If this also fails, the cause will be due to Permission issue to the repo or misspelled repo name or non-existent repo.